# How do I get my VS extension to show up in the extension manager?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

I am creating my first visual studio extension and I would like to know how I can have my extension show up in the Visual Studio Extension manager.

If you go to Tools>Extension Manager you will see what I am referring to.

When you view an extension there, it allows you to enable/disable it as well as it includes a description of it and a thumbnail image.

I am guessing I have to modify the XML in one of the files to do this. Although I am not sure where or how.  So far my extension does not show up there when I debug. Even when I create a standard extension package it doesnt.

Does the extension have to be in visual studio extension gallery first? My extension targets VS 2005-2012, and is written in C# and vb.net.(The extension project itself is C#)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for ...
please take a look at 
[Visual Studio Extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/446955/Web-Search-Visual-Studio-Add-in-Search-Google-Yaho)

Answer (score 0):

Since your "extension" is targeting VS2005, I'm guessing it's an add-in, not an extension. Extensions only target VS2010 and later. Unless you repackage your stuff as an extension (which requires some non-trivial code editing), there's no way to get it there.